# the structure of a 2-group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $ M $ be a finite group of order $2^{a+1} $ and let $ M $ have a normal subgroup $ R $ such that $|M: R|=2 $. Also we know that $ R $  is an elementary abelian subgroup of $ M $.

For example $ D_8 $ is an example for it. Is it true that for other cases $ M $ is abelian or what information is available for $ M $?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can construct examples by taking central products of copies of $D_8$; you can also construct examples ex nihilo by starting with an $a$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and an automorphism $\tau$ of order $2$ with at least one fixed point $v$ other than the identity. Then let $x$ act on $V$ as $\tau$, and set $x^2=v$; the resulting nonsplit extension of $V$ by $\mathbf{C}_2$ should have the properties you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elementary Abelian $2$-group $R$ is a ${\rm GF}(2)M/R$-module of dimension $a$. As such it is a direct sum of $t$ copies of the trivial module and $\frac{a-t}{2}$-copies of the free module of rank $1$. Then $Z(M)$ has order $2^{t},$ and there are examples of $M$ and $R$ for which every possibility of $t$ between $1$ and $a$ occur, as Arturo comments.